# Using cocos2d & box2d with cocoapods

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cocoapods

I'm having issue getting this set up.

My podfile:

```
platform :ios

pod 'cocos2d', '2.1'
pod 'box2d', '2.3.0'
```

Unfortunately, we need `CC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION` to be turned on, as it's set to `0` by default.

I tried adding a post_install hook to the podfile like so:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Pods-cocos2d'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        s = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']
        if s == nil
          s = [ '$(inherited)' ]
        end
        s.push('CC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1');
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It adds the flag as expected to the Pods-cocos2d target, however it does not seem to be inherited at any point by my main project, in spite of the `$(inherited)` variable in `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`.

Even then, if I manually edit the `CC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION` to on, I get linker errors saying that `CCPhysicsSprite` cannot be found.

Has anyone successfully set up these two libraries to work together with cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCPhysicsSprite is not a part of Box2d, it is extension of cocos2d. Maybe you not included the file into the project?

Comment: Turns out the podspec forgot to include .mm files.  I made a pull request in the Specs repo so the library is now complete when using cocoapods.